# Multiline textbox new line character regularexpressionvalidator issues

Tags: asp.net, regex, webforms

I've been trying to validate a multiline textbox. And of course it doesn't work.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="t_noteTextBox" runat="server" Width="700" Text='<%# Bind("t_note") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" MaxLength="700"  />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Special Characters not allowed." ForeColor="Red" 
    ControlToValidate="t_noteTextBox" ValidationExpression="(?m)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[ ]|[-]|[_]|[.]|[,]|[\r]|[\n])*"   Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="valInput" ControlToValidate="t_noteTextBox"  ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,740}$"
   ErrorMessage="Please enter a maximum of 740 characters"  Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The expression works fine as long as I don't add a carriage return. As soon as I go to a new line i get an error.
I even looked up and found the ?m multiline option. 
however that doesn't work either.
Testing the regex in Expresso works well.

```
(?m)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[ ]|[-]|[_]|[.]|[,]|[\r]|[\n])*
```

But as soon as I put it on the website it doesn't.
Any ideas?

Comment: what type of error are you getting

Comment: That does not work. when you go to a new line it halts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiline mode alters the behavior of the anchors (`^` or `$`), which you aren't using.

Singleline mode causes the dot metacharacter to match everything *including linefeeds*, but you aren't using the dot that way.  Like most metacharacters, the dot loses its special meaning inside a character class, so `[.]` just matches a literal `.`.

I suspect your problem is that you're allowing the validation to be done on the client side.  That is, you haven't set [EnableClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) to "false".  Client-side validation uses JavaScript instead of .NET, and the JavaScript regex flavor doesn't support inline modifiers like `(?m)` and `(?s)`.  But that shouldn't matter to you, since you aren't using the dot as a metacharacter.

This should be all you need:

```
ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z0-9_.,\s-]*"
```

Comment: I think we have an issue with asp.net changing the regex. I put in the above and asp.net is changing the code to 
`([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[ ]|[-]|[_]|[.]|[,])*`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this quite a bit.

```
(?m)([\w., -])*
```

The multiline flag `(?m)` only allows the anchors `^` and `$` to match before and after linebreaks, as opposed to start and end of string normally, so it's not doing what you want here.

If you use `\s` instead of matching a space, it will match the newline as well.

```
([\w.,\s-])*
```

Comment: Could you try this one? `^[\w\s/\n/\r.,-]*$`

Comment: I really don't know enough about asp.net to know why this fails. `\s` should match a newline in most flavors of regex as a space character. And `\r\n` should match the newline characters specifically. This seems to be not about regex but the setup of your validator.